# Retrieving map markers - angular google maps

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

How do you retrieve the collection of markers using angular google maps?
I've trying to use `var markers = $scope.map.markerscontrol.getGMarkers();` but it only returns the last item in the list.

Made a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Tl60bVydDQ3jIXqG6nIc

I wanna use the markers to calculate the bounds and map center.

Comment: Even I have this issue. Were you able to get through this?

Answer (score 0):

i think it help you.

in your HTML file:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="options" data-tap-disabled="true">
    <ui-gmap-marker 
      icon="yourModel.icon"
      idKey="yourModel.id"
      coords="yourModel.coords"
      control="markerControl">
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

and in your angular controller.

```
$scope.yourModel = {
  id: 1,
  coords = {
    latitude: position.latitude,
    longitude: position.longitude
  },
  icon = 'path/to/icon.png'
};
$scope.markerControl = {};
```

and how to use

```
var marker = $scope.markerControl.getGMarkers();
// marker variable, get an array of object to use.
```